# Trying to get the latest beta of Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to upgrade to the latest beta of Dart.  According to [Get the Dart SDK](https://dart.dev/get-dart#release-channels), the latest beta is currently `2.12.0-259.14.beta`.  However, when I run `flutter upgrade`, it lists `Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-259.12.beta)`.  Why is it not giving me the latest beta?

Comment: What does `flutter channel` shows you ? Note, a specific `flutter version` may be built with a specific `dart` engine, and that's probably why you don't see the latest `dart` engine.

Comment: The latest Flutter build does not necessarily have the latest build of Dart. Seeing as how they are two different projects with their own development teams, one is always going to lag behind the other (and frankly I'm amazed that they are even that close).

Comment: @iamauser `flutter channel` shows that I am on the beta channel.